# C program not entering for loop, but executing everything right up until it

Tags: c, for-loop

for some reason when running a program it refuses to enter a for loop, and rather just hangs.

```
main()
{      

    char *buffer;
    int chunk_offset, current_chunk_number, total_chunks;
    int filelen;

    filelen = ReadFileintoBuffer( buffer);  
        printf("file read \n");                             // error break point 1


    int events = filelen/eventlen;      // number of 512 + 2 32 bit events events with timecode

    int sp = 0;
    int i,j;
    int toterror[25];
    printf("file of length %d has %d events \n", filelen, events);
    printf(" i = %d \n", i);
    for( i = 0; i < events; i++)
    {
        printf("analyzed %d events of %d", i, events);
        sp=0;
        int error[13];

        Analyzeevent(buffer+i*eventlen, error);

        if(error[0])
        {
            sp = 12;
        }
        for( j =1; j < 13; j++)
        {
            toterror[j+sp] += error[j];
        }

    }
    printf("post for loop");
    Printerrs(toterror, events);
    exit(0);

}
```

It prints everything down to i = (9727988 in this particular case), then nothing. it all just stops. any idea what happened? i learned c++ and programming in c is very strange and awkward for me right now. compiler doesnt throw up any warnings or anything

thank you for your help in advance.

edit: for ring0 heres the code to ReadFileintoBuffer:

```
int ReadFileintoBuffer( char *buffer)
{ 
    int filelen;
    char text[200];
    printf("Input File:  " );
    scanf( "%s" ,text);
    FILE *file = 0;

    int i;


    //Open file
    file = fopen(text, "rb");
    if (!file)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file \n");
        exit(0);

    }

    //Get file length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);               // find the end of the file
    filelen=ftell(file);                    // set the current pointer (currently at end from above) as file length
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);               // set pointer back to beginning of file

    //Allocate memory
    buffer=(char *)malloc(filelen+1);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error! \n");
                                fclose(file);
        return;
    }

    //Read file contents into buffer
    fread(buffer, filelen, 1, file);
    fclose(file);                           // clse the file, all in buffer now
    return filelen;
}
```

Comment: Did you habitually omit the return type of the `main` function in C++? K&R C assumes default `int`, but that's not the case with ANSI C and hasn't been considered "best practice" for quite some time...

Comment: Also, have you stepped through the code with a debugger? It's likely that the value of `events` is such that it is always less than 0, causing the `for` loop not to run. You'd see the same behavior in your more familiar C++.

Comment: You are not using a debugger.   As soon as you start to use a debugger, the problem will become immediately obvious.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes and no.  The implicit int rule was still in the 1989 ANSI C standard, and the equivalent 1990 ISO C standard.  But the rule was dropped in ISO C99, which ANSI officially adopted (and I presume ANSI has recently adopted the new ISO C11 standard).  So omitting the return type of `main` is permitted in what's commonly referred to as "ANSI C", but not in the standard that ANSI has officially adopted.  (And it's never been a particularly good idea.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be getting some buffering issues with printf.  Try adding a \n to the print inside the for loop.  (Like you have in some of the earlier prints)

It may be executing all the code but you aren't seeing the printed result.

Comment: Or entering the loop, printing the first line (and buffering, as @DYoung says) and then hanging inside `Analyzeevent()`

Comment: adding a \n did indeed fix that particular error. thank you!. though i dont quite understand why that happens. i'll have to look into the buffer that printf uses. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a debugger - `gdb`

What is `eventlen` here? What is its type? What is its value and `filelen`'s value?

```
int events = filelen/eventlen;
```

It could be possible that your `event` is negative and so refusing to enter this loop!

```
for( i = 0; i < events; i++)
```

Comment: ah, i put events into one of the print statements before that to check, and events is in the thousands.

Answer (score 0):

`eventlen` is not defined prior to this line:

```
int events = filelen/eventlen;
```

Use printf to see its value.

Comment: oh sorry, eventlen is defined outside main with several other constants i want easy access to.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at

```
  char *buffer;
  filelen = ReadFileintoBuffer( buffer);
```

it seems something is not going right.
We don't see the code of `ReadFileintoBuffer` but it cannot use the `buffer` parameter in any way:

- `buffer` is a non allocated string
- its value, and not its reference, is passed to the function

Thus, either

- `buffer` should be allocated prior to calling `ReadFileintoBuffer()`, eg with malloc() or
- its referenced should be passed instead, like

  ```
  filelen = ReadFileintoBuffer( &buffer);
  ```

It all depends on the ReadFileintoBuffer() function.


**Edit based on** `ReadFileintoBuffer()` **code**

The code has a problem with `buffer` as expected.
The local `buffer` parameter is allocated in the function, but its pointer  value is not copied into the caller's `buffer`.

There are several ways to fix this - one of which is, as mentioned above, to pass the reference to the `buffer` pointer, and not its value to the function.

```
  filelen = ReadFileintoBuffer( &buffer); // note the &
```

And the function itself - `buffer` related:

```
int ReadFileintoBuffer( char **buffer) // note the **
{ 
    // ...

    //Allocate memory ( using *buffer instead of buffer )
    *buffer=(char *)malloc(filelen+1);

    if (!*buffer)
    {
      // ...
    }

    //Read file contents into   *buffer
    fread(*buffer, filelen, 1, file);
    // ...
}
```

This way the `main()` buffer variable allocation is actually performed by that function.

Note that the solution you approved does not fix the problem: it just empties the `printf` buffer... Unless `buffer` is fixed, your program cannot run correctly.

Comment: this  program was me learning c through hacking another researchers code to bits and frankensteining it to do what i want. heres the code in readfileintobuffer, i've always been terrible at file I/O so i likely made several mistakes here, but it seems to be working...

    i'll edit it into the main question

Comment: Please have a look at my answer that has been updated. The actual problem of your program was indeed an allocation issue with `buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to catch some problem by intermittent printf's, than use them with fflush'es. \n  works as a such, too. Or you can't say nothing looking at seeming hanging app.